# How to define the "=" equals sign as a Bash alias?

Tags: bash, alias, keyword, equals-operator

I want to define the `=` equals sign as a Bash alias but Bash does not allow any of the following definitions:

```
alias =='echo foo'
alias \=='echo foo'
alias -- =='echo foo'
alias -- \=='echo foo'
```

Does someone know a notation that works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a function:

```
=() { echo "foo"; }
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question though, aliases behave differently than functions.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the reserved special chars, used for assignment and test and you cannot use it for alias. More info: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html#EQREF